# On Ubuntu Touch, how can I download files from e-mail web clients?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, attachment

I use the ProtonMail and the GMail e-mail web applications on Ubuntu Touch. I want to download any files attached to e-mails I access using these web clients.

However, when I attempt to download an attached file like a compressed archive (.tgz) I am presented with an **Open with** page that states:

> "Sorry, there aren't currently any apps installed that can handle this type of content."

I don't want to "handle" the attachment in any way other than to download it. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to your email account from the browser app (instead of webapps or Dekko), you'll see an option to simply download the file (along with opening with another app if the file type is supported).

There is a [feature request](http://pad.lv/1560086) at Launchpad to include an option to download arbitrary file types from the webapps.